c# - vsto outlook - ribbon and Form Region combination
I am creating an add-in for outlook using VSTO. Using Ribbon(Visual Designer) I have created a new tab in outlook. And when I click on this tab I need a new page to appear. To create a new page I used Outlook Form Region.  But it is not displayed in the tab I created. Can you tell me how I can display a page created with Outlook Form Region when I click on a tab created with Ribbon (Visual Designer)?

Sidenote the new outlook has no COM support. So VSTO is a dead end. The new Outlook is a webapp even on the desktop.
